# How to place divs three in a row with css and html

Tags: html, css

I want to place 3 images in a row and 3 images blow in a row on an html page using divs and css. I can place 3 images in a row but cant get the other images to display in a row below, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my html

```
  <div id="ballons">

       <img src="ballons.png" alt="ballons"/>
       <br>
       <center><a href="">Ballons</a></center>


     </div>

     <div id="cake">

        <img src="cake.png" alt="cake"/>

        <br>
       <center><a href="">Cake</a></center>

      </div>

      <div id ="candles">

        <img src="candles.png" alt="candles"/>

          <br>
       <cnter><a href="">Candles</a></center>

      </div>


      <div id ="bag">

        <img src="bag.png" alt="party bag"/>

<br>
            <center><a href="">Party Bag</a></center>

      </div>

<div id ="boncey">
        <img src="boncey.png" alt="boncey castle"/>

<br>
            <center><a href="">Boncey Castle</a></center>

      </div>

<div id="paper">
          <img src="paper.png" alt="paper plate"/>


<br>
            <center><a href="">Papaer Plates and Cup</a></center>


      </div>
```

Here is my css

```
#ballons
{

    padding-top: 60px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 150px;
    float: left;
     }

#cake
{
    padding-top: 60px;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;


}

#candles

{
    padding-top: 60px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;

}

#bag
{
    padding-top: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 150px;
     position: relative;
 }

#boncey
{
    padding-top: 60px;

    width: 250px;
     position: relative;
    }

#paper
{
    padding-top: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Trying to simulate a grid with a bunch of ID selectors is rarely a good Idea. Take a look at grids like Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro)  and you'll see that they use common classes to abstract the CSS, making it reusable and much less complex.

Comment: Try enclosing all the divs in a parent div and give that div some `fixed height`. So that the 4th child div will move to the next line automatically as it won't find any space in previous row.

Comment: The center element was made obsolete in HTML5 and should no longer be used. Also, the img tag is self-closing and does not use or need a closing slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.  You'll have to adjust width, height, etc for what you're looking to do, but this gives you an idea how to have the items in rows, with photo over title in this case.  It also is easily adapted to be responsive.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kdt2b9s/)

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="rowitem">
        <img src="ballons.png" alt="ballons"/>
        <span><a href="">Ballons</a></span>        
    </div>
    <div class="rowitem">
        <img src="cake.png" alt="ballons"/>
        <span><a href="">Cake</a></span>        
    </div>
    <div class="rowitem">
        <img src="candles.png" alt="ballons"/>
        <span><a href="">candles</a></span>        
    </div>

</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="rowitem">
        <img src="bag.png" alt="ballons"/>
        <span><a href="">Bag</a></span>        
    </div>
    <div class="rowitem">
        <img src="boncy.png" alt="ballons"/>
        <span><a href="">boncy</a></span>        
    </div>
    <div class="rowitem">
        <img src="streamer.png" alt="ballons"/>
        <span><a href="">streamer</a></span>        
    </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
.rowitem {
    display:inline-block;

}

.rowitem img {
    display:block;

}
.clearfix {
    clear:both;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep your structure, you can add float:left to the bottom 3 divs and then add a `div:nth-child(4n) {clear:left;}` style.  But I would wrap all the divs in a container div with a fixed width so they don't wrap when you minimize the window - unless you want them to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to make a custom grid solution with specific ID selectors is not really a good idea. The best way to make a grid is to use an expandable solution that works with classes. There are many solutions like this, including Bootstrap (which was mentioned in the comments).

I, personally, like [Toast](http://daneden.github.io/Toast/) by Dan Eden. It's very expandable and easy to use.

1. To use it, go to the [repo](https://github.com/daneden/toast) and download the zip.
2. Open the files. Go to Toast-master > css > grid.css
3. Put grid.css into your project.
4. Link it like so:
5. And use it like this (it's responsive and flexible):

   ```
   <div class="container">
       <div class="grid">
           <div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-3">

           </div>
           <div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-3">

           </div>
           <div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-3">

           </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```